# CVS Web frontend

Tags: cvs, collaboration

Is there any free WEB application, that can be installed and pointed to any CVS server, that would show commits as they arrive, allow to search them, and possibly present nice diffs, and visual representation of branches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.gjt.org/src/cvsweb/
http://www.viewvc.org/